# How can I loop multiple datasets through a data step or proc sql query SAS?

Tags: loops, sas, macros, sas-macro, proc-sql

I have multiple datasets (100+) that all contain the same 3 columns (code_num, replicate, total_qty) each with a distinct code (code_num).

```
data code_num_1
code_num replicate total_qty
12345       376       45
12345       76        67
12345       943       300
.
.

data code_num_2
code_num replicate total_qty
12234       85       746
12234       900      35
12234       726      273
.
.
```

and etc.

I would like to run those datasets through a data step if possible:

```
data test;
set test_; <-- datasets will go here...
if _N_ in(&PercentileRow10,&PercentileRow20,&PercentileRow30,&PercentileRow40,&PercentileRow50,&PercentileRow60,&PercentileRow70, &PercentileRow80,&PercentileRow90);
run;
```

*Note: &percentilerow is a macro variable that will obtain the percentiles from the datasets. The column quantity will determine percentiles. I have this step beforehand:

```
proc sql no print;
```

create table ___ as
select code_num,
replicate,
sum(qty) as total_qty
from ____
group by code_num, replicate
order by total_qty;
quit;

Ideally, I would like to obtain the percentiles of each dataset and create a new dataset that will have each percentile and the associated replicate it occurred and the total quantity. Could I use a macro and do loop to run my datasets through this data set to produce new datasets?

```
data code_num_1_perc
percentile replicate qty
10           87      45
20           933     65
30           34      100
.
.
90           467      837
```

This is my ideal output for each dataset code_num_#. If possible

Comment: Huh?  Do you just want to combine multiple dataset into a single dataset? You can list multiple dataset on the SET statement. No looping is required.  But the logic of IF statement looks suspect. Why is it testing `_N_` automatic variable?

Comment: Note that an exact percentile value may not be in the data set, what do you want to happen in that case? A percentile can be an average of values in the case of ties or even number of observations.

Comment: Why is &percentileRow10 duplicated?

Comment: Typo @Reeza and Not sure, I haven't ran into that scenario yet. Before I was running this data step without stratifying the code numbers (code_num) in a proc surveyselect and a proc surveyselect would bootstrap the whole population rather than per code number. I am now looking at it per code number. From there, I would like to obtain the percentiles from each code number instead of percentiles of a population of code numbers, hence why I thought splitting them into different datasets in hopes to obtain the ideal output above.

Comment: You will definitely run into this scenario of a percentile not being an exact value in your data set. So how do you get the qty and replicate for a percentile value that is not a data point in your data?

Comment: Gotcha @Reeza obtaining the percentile is based on the quantity column. The replicate column represents what iteration (from that proc surveyselect) that amount of quantity it occurred in. Hope that answers your question?

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit the data set. In the ideal data set described above in my question post. The column replicate will represent what replicate # (from the proc surveyselect) occurred on the _ percentile. For example, replicate 87 out of 1000 happened to occur on the 90th row which is the 10th percentile. Sorry I didn't have this info in my initial post. @Reeza

Comment: Not sure how that changes anything with the issue I'm referring to. See the example in my answer. Your results do not align with the sample data so it's not a reproducible example that illustrates your full problem.

Comment: @Reeza I see, thanks! So I have a step that does: proc sql no print; create table ___ as select code_num, replicate, sum(qty) as total_qty from ____ group by code_num, replicate order by total_qty; quit...if this step helps

Comment: Did you try the solution suggested?

Comment: I did, thank you! I should have 10 rows per code_num right? For some code_nums, it only shows 1 or 5 rows (ranks)...@Reeza

Comment: Then you have a lot of ties in your quantities and the deciles are the same. Take a look at your data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirements correct, the proposed methodology is flawed.

For example, the median (50th percentile) of a series such as
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 is 5.5. 5.5 is not a value in the data set so how would a replicate number be selected?

My recommendation would be a different process altogether. Look into PROC RANK to see how ties are handled and how you'd like them handled. You didn't specify which variable would used to calculate the percentiles.

1. Combine all data sets into one, adding in a data set identifier to uniquely identify each data set.

```
data combined;
length source data_set_name $50.;
set code_num_: indsname = source;
data_set_name = source;
run;
```

2. Use PROC RANK to group into deciles

```
proc rank data=combined out=combined_deciles groups=10;
by data_set_name;
var total_qty;
ranks PRanks;
run;
```

3. Get the first (or last, based on requirements) value for each rank

```
data want;
set combined_deciles;
by datasetName Pranks;
if first.Pranks;
run;
```

Comment: When processing a stack of data sets in such a manner consider using a DATA Step VIEW instead of copying all the data into a new data set.